# Key function in mapping options not working

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I'm having trouble understanding the `key` function in the mapping options for the mapping plugin in KnockoutJS. Based on the documentation I understand that the key function will tell the mapping plugin what property to use to determine if an object is new or old.

They use this example... http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html#advanced_usage

But it says..

> This way, every time the mapping plugin checks an item in the children array, it will only look at the id property to determine if an object was completely replaced or merely needs updating.

What does "needs updating" mean? It will update the whole `children` object? It will update only the properties in the `children` object that have changed? I'm confused.

Their example is simple, I can't get it to work with a sample of more realistic data. Here is a jsFiddle of my problem... http://jsfiddle.net/rQfpr/1/

In my example I'm trying to just replace the `UserMovies` object in `self.movies[1]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a JSFiddle that might help you understand the interaction:

NOTE: The 'update' entry in the mapping was just so I could log to the console... it isn't needed unless you need to customize how updates happen.

http://jsfiddle.net/jearles/wgZ59/49/

Hit 'Load Matrix' and it will display:

```
12
23
34
```

Click 'Change' and it will reload the matrix:

```
24
45
```

Looking at the console messages I post you see:

```
Creating 1
Updating 1
Creating 2
Updating 2
Creating 3
Updating 3
Updating 2
Creating 4
Updating 4
```

This confirms the actions that the mapping plugin is performing.

Initially:

```
12 - Is created and updated
23 - Is created and updated
34 - Is created and updated
```

On update:

```
12 - Is deleted
23 - Is changed to 24
34 - Is deleted
45 - Is added
```

--

The 'key' entry helps the mapping plugin determine which entries are new or existing by designating a particular property as being the "key"; otherwise the entire object is compared for equality.

Comment: Is the key used as the comparison for the whole object? So in my case is Id used to compare just the UserMovies items or the whole movies collection? The documentation makes it seem like it will use the Id to field to compare just the UserMovies items, not the whole collection.

Comment: It's used to compare individual items inside the observableArray... in your case UserMovie objects.